# File sync iphone4 (ios5) auto camera-upload doesn't work

Tags: file-sharing, iphone

Basically the Camera Roll auto-upload feature does not seem to work, nothing is happening, no files exist in the "Pictures - name" folder.

I have a few questions on this:

1. How do I know if auto uploading is actually ongoing?
2. When will U1 File app be syncing; when app is active and/or running in background, always, other?
3. Will it upload all photos on my Iphone, Camera Roll and Photo Stream?
4. When I navigate the the Pictures-name folder in U1 Files and add a photo from my Cameraroll, should something happen? (as it is now, nothing happens)
5. Could I expect U1 Files to work on IOS 5.0.1?

Sincerely
Knut

Answer (score 1):

Well today, 22 days after  u1 files installation was installed it finally started syncing.

U1 files seems to sync when app is in foreground.

I am still running ios 5.0.1.